# Python Flask, how to set content type

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask and I return an XML file from a get request. How do I set the content type to xml ?

e.g.

```
@app.route('/ajax_ddl')
def ajax_ddl():
    xml = 'foo'
    header("Content-type: text/xml")
    return xml
```

Answer (score 341, accepted):

Try like this:

```
from flask import Response
@app.route('/ajax_ddl')
def ajax_ddl():
    xml = 'foo'
    return Response(xml, mimetype='text/xml')
```

The actual Content-Type is based on the mimetype parameter and the charset (defaults to UTF-8).

Response (and request) objects are documented here: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/

Comment: Is it possible to set these and other options on a global level (ie: default)?

Comment: @earthmeLon, make a subclass of `flask.Response`, override the `default_mimetype` class attribute, and set that as `app.response_class`
http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseResponse.default_mimetype
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.response_class

Comment: @earthmeLon: If you set `app.response_class` like Simon points out, remember to use `app.make_response` to get your reponse instance like [pointed out in the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31751634/110204).

Comment: Requests with browsers or postman work fine with this approach, however curl does not work well with the returned Response object. Curl will just print "Found". With curl "return content, status_code, header" seem to work better.

Answer (score 191):

As simple as this

```
x = "some data you want to return"
return x, 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css; charset=utf-8'}
```

Update:
Use the method below because it will work with both python 2.x and python 3.x and it eliminates the "multiple header" problem (potentially emitting multiple, duplicate headers).

```
from flask import Response
r = Response(response="TEST OK", status=200, mimetype="application/xml")
r.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
return r
```

Comment: The simplest solution. Definitely should be the accepted answer

Comment: There is a drawback: it allows you only ADD headers. When I did it, I ended up with two Content-Type headers in response - default one and added one.

Comment: @omikron I have updated the answer, try the new method it should work.

Comment: @HarshDaftary it is unclear to me which is the new method and which is the old. Could you please replace "this method" with "the method above" or "the method below"?

Comment: @Leo I added the desired clarification.

Comment: Why do you have to set both the `mimetype` argument and the `content-type` header? What's the difference?

Comment: > "why both" 
@étale-cohomology the accepted answer [11774026](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11774026/) links to the werkzeug's `werkzeug.wrappers.Response` object documentation which answers the difference. TL;DR: mimetype is just the mimetype only and is `Like content_type, but without parameters (eg, without charset, type etc.) and always lowercase.` So, the above answer is doing redundant work. Refer the accepted answer.

Answer (score 54):

I like and upvoted @Simon Sapin's answer.  I ended up taking a slightly different tack, however, and created my own decorator:

```
from flask import Response
from functools import wraps

def returns_xml(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        r = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return Response(r, content_type='text/xml; charset=utf-8')
    return decorated_function
```

and use it thus:

```
@app.route('/ajax_ddl')
@returns_xml
def ajax_ddl():
    xml = 'foo'
    return xml
```

I think this is slightly more comfortable.

Comment: When returning both a response and a status code like `return 'msg', 200`, this will lead to `ValueError: Expected bytes`. Instead, change the decorator to `return Response(*r, content_type='whatever')`. It will unpack the tuple to arguments. Thank you though, for an elegant solution!

Answer (score 31):

Use the [make_response method](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.make_response) to get a response with your data. Then set the [mimetype attribute](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Response.mimetype). Finally return this response:

```
@app.route('/ajax_ddl')
def ajax_ddl():
    xml = 'foo'
    resp = app.make_response(xml)
    resp.mimetype = "text/xml"
    return resp
```

If you use `Response` directly, you lose the chance to customize the responses by setting `app.response_class`. The `make_response` method uses the `app.responses_class` to make the response object. In this you can create your own class, add make your application uses it globally:

```
class MyResponse(app.response_class):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyResponse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_cookie("last-visit", time.ctime())

app.response_class = MyResponse
```

Comment: This is essentially @SimonSapin's accepted answer repackaged.

Comment: @J0e3gan thanks. I have expanded my answer to better explain why using `make_response` is better than using `Response`

Answer (score 23):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/user/xml')
def user_xml():
    resp = make_response(render_template('xml/user.html', username='Ryan'))
    resp.headers['Content-type'] = 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
    return resp
```

Comment: I think this answer is important because it makes clear how to change the headers on something from a render_template.

Answer (score 10):

You can try the following method(python3.6.2)：

case one：

```
@app.route('/hello')
def hello():

    headers={ 'content-type':'text/plain' ,'location':'http://www.stackoverflow'}
    response = make_response('<h1>hello world</h1>',301)
    response.headers = headers
    return response
```

case two：

```
@app.route('/hello')
def hello():

    headers={ 'content-type':'text/plain' ,'location':'http://www.stackoverflow.com'}
    return '<h1>hello world</h1>',301,headers
```

I am using Flask .And if you want to  return json,you can write this:

```
import json # 
@app.route('/search/<keyword>')
def search(keyword):

    result = Book.search_by_keyword(keyword)
    return json.dumps(result),200,{'content-type':'application/json'}


from flask import jsonify
@app.route('/search/<keyword>')
def search(keyword):

    result = Book.search_by_keyword(keyword)
    return jsonify(result)
```

Answer (score 5):

Usually you don’t have to create the [`Response`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Response) object yourself because [`make_response()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.make_response) will take care of that for you.

```
from flask import Flask, make_response                                      
app = Flask(__name__)                                                       

@app.route('/')                                                             
def index():                                                                
    bar = '<body>foo</body>'                                                
    response = make_response(bar)                                           
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'            
    return response
```

---

One more thing, it seems that no one mentioned the [`after_this_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.after_this_request), I want to say something:

[`after_this_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.after_this_request)

> Executes a function after this request. This is useful to modify response objects. The function is passed the response object and has to return the same or a new one.

so we can do it with [`after_this_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.after_this_request), the code should look like this:

```
from flask import Flask, after_this_request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    @after_this_request
    def add_header(response):
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        return response
    return '<body>foobar</body>'
```

Answer (score 2):

When sending files

```
from flask import send_file

@app.route("/graph", methods = ['GET'])
def grafh():
    return send_file('graph.png', mimetype='image/png', as_attachment=False)
```

Change as_attachment if you want it previewed or as download