# How can I return an XML file with Spyne?

Tags: python, xml, web-services, return, spyne

I have **Flask-Spyne** server (web service) and I want to return (return to client after he will ask) a **XML file**.

**I want to do this:**

- I will put some things from database to XML. (**solved**)
- I have that XML saved on server (webservice) and I want to send it to client when he ask. (**this is a problem**)

Is there a way how to do it?

**Here is mine code:**

```
class Service(spyne.Service):
    __service_url_path__ = '/soap';
    __in_protocol__ = Soap11(validator='lxml');
    __out_protocol__ = Soap11();

    @spyne.srpc(DateTime, DateTime, _returns="What to put here?")
    def Function(A,B):
        GetXML(A,B)
        s = open("file.xml");
        return s;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '127.0.0.1');
```

**Thank You very much** for any help.. :)

**EDIT:**

So, this is mine code now: (sending string)

```
@spyne.srpc(DateTime, DateTime, _returns=Iterable(Unicode))
    def oracle(A,B):
        GetXML(A,B)
        s = open("file.xml");
        return s
```

Comment: you should properly compose a http response with correct mime type as 'text/xml, refer this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773348/python-flask-how-to-set-content-type

Comment: @Sugam Thanks, will try

Comment: @Sugam And, What should I put to _returns?

Comment: yes, the xml variable should contain your xml string

Comment: @Sugam Wait, I am little confused... :) Could you write me just little code (how that def oracle should look)?

Comment: Where does the "Databaze.xml" file come from? is that generated by Spyne as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return it as a regular string inside a document, you must set your _return type to `Unicode`.

If you want to return it as an xml document, you must parse it (`etree.parse("Databaze.xml")`) and return the resulting ElementTree instance. Your return type in this case should be `AnyXml`.

Also see these examples:

https://github.com/plq/spyne/blob/1f214d102913848cf9d18985d2d75ae1a97375de/examples/response_as_file_dynamic.py

https://github.com/plq/spyne/blob/1f214d102913848cf9d18985d2d75ae1a97375de/examples/response_as_xml_file.py

Sending as string isolates your document from parent context. It's a bit more inefficient (e.g. `<` character becomes `&lt;`) but otherwise harmless.

Sending as document makes your document part of the SOAP message. It's more efficient but makes it inherit namespace prefixes from the parent document which may cause slight changes to the document -- i.e. what you put in and what you get back out may not be equal byte-for-byte (but equivalent nevertheless).

It totally depends on the use case. If in doubt, return as string.

Comment: Thank You very much :). For now, I did it with string. Can you tell me, if there is any difference in sending string or xml document? In speed, usability.. :)

Comment: So, If I am returning string and it is good for me now and I am satisfied, it is good and I dont have to change it :) Thank You very much

Comment: Sorry for interrupting again :) But could you write me, how it will look, if I want send xml document with AnyXml? I edited my post with string sending code.. Thank you

Comment: I already answered your question. If you want another answer, you need to ask another question. Or just read the docs, you know.

Comment: Ok, will do.. Thank you