# How to return plain text from flask endpoint? Needed by Prometheus

Tags: python, flask, plaintext

I need to setup a `/metrics` endpoint so that Prometheus can consume statistics about an endpoint. How do I go about doing this?

I have this in my Flask app:

```
@app.route('/metrics')
def metrics():
    def generateMetrics():
        metrics = ""
        ... some string builder logic
        return metrics

    response = make_response(generateMetrics(), 200)
    response.mimetype = "text/plain"
    return response
```

Is this the best way? What is the difference between returning a String (just returning `metrics` here) and returning plain text? Why do I need the mimetype?

Answer (score 31):

**Is this the best way?**

There are several ways to set the MIME type, better explained and discussed [in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11773348/2732991). Your way works fine and gets the job done.

**What is the difference between returning a String and returning plain text?**

If you return a string Flask will automatically [handle some of the Response logic for you](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/#about-responses). This means using some default values. If you set up two different endpoints you'll see that the difference turns out to be that your code returns the following header:

```
Content-Type:"text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

While just returning a string (and default MIME type) would return the following header:

```
Content-Type:"text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

**Why do I need the mimetype?**

You might say that it is technically more correct, given that your response is simply plain text, and not HTML. However, a more forcing reason for needing it would be that a third party system you are using (Prometheus) relies on or cares about the contents of the "Content-Type" header. If they do, then you must set it for them to accept it.

**Example code**

For the Content-Type header demonstration I used the following example Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
app = Flask(__name__)


def generateMetrics():
    return "hello world"


@app.route('/metrics')
def metrics():
    response = make_response(generateMetrics(), 200)
    response.mimetype = "text/plain"
    return response


@app.route('/metrics2')
def metrics2():
    return generateMetrics()
```

I then viewed the returned body and headers using Postman.