# How can I open a txt file

Tags: python, flask

The file contains information, I understand that I need to open the file and read its contents, maybe open it in a dictionary?

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def read_file():
    text = open(r'/Users/dev/Desktop/new_project/requiremets.txt')
    text.readline()
    return text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: You want to set the response type as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773348/python-flask-how-to-set-content-type except that instead of "text/xml" I think it would be "application/text"

Comment: You can try `return text.read()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should writhe the following for reading a file:

```
f = open("text.txt","r") # 'r' for read, 'w' for write, if binaries add a b to one of those
```

To acces the file you then write:

```
f.read()
```

and then you can return it in your function. It'd look like this:

```
def read_file('/'):
    f = open("text.txt","r")
    return f.read()
```

Note: Use `readlines()` instead of `read()` to return a list with the content of the lines.