# Html form not working when used inside Flask class based view

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to improve my code by splitting it into methods —get and post.

The code that works:

```
@app.route('/send', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file:
            // do sth//
            return 'result'

    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new Filess</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''
```

But when I try to change it to a class and split into get and post methods it displays string instead of html form.

Updated code:

```
class Form(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return '''
        <!doctype html>
        <title>Upload new Filess</title>
        <h1>Upload new File</h1>
        <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
          <input type=file name=file>
          <input type=submit value=Upload>
        </form>
        '''

    def post(self):
        file = request.files['file']
        if file:
            // do sth//
            return 'result'

api.add_resource(Form, '/send')
```

I can't see the issue.
I have tried changing the form but it seems that the issue is not connected to the form.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a [content type header<sup>[stackoverflow]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11774026/16770846) to tell the browser what is coming through so that it knows how to handle that.